# Mean Well power supply voltage adjustment

Tags: voltage, switch-mode-power-supply

I am using a Mean Well RD-125A dual switching power supply which supplies both 5 V and 12 V. It has a screw that adjusts the voltage for both. My issue is it doesn't give an exact 12 V AND 5 V. It looks like I'll have to choose between below voltage or above.

**My question is what would be the safest option for my 12 V and 5 V devices?** I am worried about damaging them if the voltage is higher or lower over time, but maybe the increased/decreased amount is safe enough, I don't know hence the question.

Using the voltage adjuster here are the values for 12 V, 5 V, and a somewhat middle range.

12 V
5.8 V

11.2 V
5.5 V

10.23 V
5 V

For reference, here is the [data sheet for the Mean Well RD-125A](https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/Products/ProdDS/323741.PDF).

Comment: Are you measuring these voltages with a load on both the 5V and 12V outputs? If so, how much current are you drawing from each? If not, can you add a small load and measure the voltages again?

Comment: Are you going to guess how much current you need and Voltage tolerance in your question?

Comment: Unless you show us what  you are using , how can we guess what is Absolute Max safe for 5V logic and what affects performance ( analog 12V for low voltage?  assuming 10% tolerance for both and add preload and set for worse case

Comment: I am currently supplying it with 2.5amps of 5v and 2amps of 12v to test. In the end I intend to use 7.3amps 12v and 3.6amps 5v. Devices will be led buttons, led strips, sound amplifier and usb hub.

Answer (score 2):

All PC PSU's started out with the intention of a minimum load sharing and so they used a common primary transformer coil and high mutual coupling so only one driver.  They usually needed 10% preload on 5V to work at all 20 yrs ago.  This was a major cost reduction.

Here in the fine print the specs are defined by **Load Regulation** error.  **5V=1%, 12V=5%** but with the **other supply loaded with 60% and step load from 20% to 100%.**

**Your question needs a design load {Min:Max} as a spec for each channel and a tolerance.**

It  can be 5% if you like or 10% if you show what you are doing or 1% if you expecting too much.  Just give the details and it can be sorted out.

This is also called **crossload regulation error** which is not given but can be figured out if you tell us what/why you need accuracy or low noise. This CLR error is often specified by better suppliers.

[image]

If you need 5% V tolerance on 12V from 20 to 100% step load, then the spec says you need 23W load out of 38.5W rated on the 5V rail.  So you may need a dummy load.  The less 5V load, the poorer tracking of 5V and 12V as a ratio from Pot adjust.

Answer (score 1):

Let's check RD-125 datasheet:

[image]

There is a minimum load spec: notice the "Current Range" is 2-15A for 5V channel, and 0.5-10A for 12V channel. Accurate voltage regulation is not guaranteed if the load does not draw the minimum current.

[image]

Looking at the block diagram the reason becomes clear: only Channel 1 (5V) is regulated via a feedback loop. Channel 2 (12V) is open loop and unregulated.

So you have to adjust the 5V output with the potentiometer while your intended load is drawing its usual current... and you will get "approximately 12V" on the other output.

Also the 12V output will fluctuate depending on current draw on the 5V output.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you recommend I adjust the potentiometer to 5v exactly with my intended load, making sure it’s within the 2-15A, and then and only then I’ll get closer to 12v?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.